# Nginx + PHP-FPM slow with more concurrent AJAX requests

Tags: nginx, php

I switched from common LAMP stack (Linux+Apache+MySQL+PHP) to **nginx** + PHP-FPM mostly because of the speed. The speed increase is incredible - not measured but it looks like for a project using both Zend (old libraries) and Zend 2 (new apps) for backend and Bootstrap + CoffeeScript + Backbone.js on the frontend the site renders 2 to 3 times faster!

The only drawback is for pages on which too many concurrent AJAX requests are called. Most of the times one page calls up to 5 different AJAX requests to load data on render but few of them require even 10 to 20 concurrent requests. In this case the rendering is slowed down 2 to 4 times when compared to rendering on Apache (comparison could now be done only on two different servers while the one running Apache is older and overall slower - but it can render pages with many concurrent AJAX requests much quicker).

This is my PHP-FPM configuration (regarding the pool manager):

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
```

Increasing `pm.max_children` to `40` doesn't seem to have any influence on the speed though after changing from the default value `5` to current `20` I could see some speed increase.

I have also increased the `worker_processes` for nginx to value `4` (number of the cores) while keeping the `worker_connections` on the default `1024` value.

Is there anything else I should change in order to make the pages with more concurrent AJAX requests running much faster?

Comment: I am sure OPCache is enabled on production servers. And yes, I am talking to the unix socket directly.

Comment: What if you set the pm to static with max children to 30 (or whatever your hardware can support, also check the PHP memory limit to make sure (memlimit * maxchildren) < total server RAM.

Comment: Could you show you Nginx configuration as well?